# mouse event listener is not working in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple game as The Odin Project exercise called "ETCH-A-SKETCH". When mouse goes over squares they supposed to change color. But I can't get the onmouseover event to work. What do you think is the problem?

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <title>ETCH-A-SKETCH</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container"></div>
    
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

app.js

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const Btn = document.createElement('button');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
body.append(Btn);
body.insertBefore(Btn, container);
Btn.innerText = 'Create A New Grid';

....

squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.addEventListener('onmouseover', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        square.classList.add('zapper');
    });
});
```

style.css

```
.zapper {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.zapper:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: `'onmouseover'` -> `'mouseover'`

Comment: You use the `on` prefix when declaring the event within the html (ie: `<div onclick=func()>` but omit when declared within the `addEventListener` constructor

Comment: You want to change color using CSS, not Javascript.

Comment: @connexo What do you suggest. square.style.backgroundColor = 'black' ?? This is fine, except the mouse event doesn't trigger to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **event listeners**, it should be `mouseover` not `onmouseover`

like this:

```js
square.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
```

if you want to use `onmouseover`, it should be used in **html attributes** like this

```html
<button onmouseover="functionName()">
```

the `on` prefix is used for html attributes, remove the `on` when you are using event listeners

Comment: I did change it to mouseover, but the problem persists.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that JavaScript is very fast. Basically what happens is that yow code finishes before the dom is rendered, there for when it wants to add en event to yow items, them items still not in the screen. You need to tell JavaScript to add the listener after the dom mounted

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');

const body = document.querySelector('body');
const Btn = document.createElement('button');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
body.append(Btn);
body.insertBefore(Btn, container);
Btn.innerText = 'Create A New Grid';

....

squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.addEventListener('onmouseover', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        square.classList.add('zapper');
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks. It did need it. But, the problem persists. Note that onmouseover was replaced by mouseover.